# Dealing with escaped spaces when using Server.MapPath on a URI

Tags: asp.net

The following code does not work as intended when there is a space in the filename. Uri.AbsolutePath escapes the string, resulting in the mapped path on disk also including the unnecessary escaped characters:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/my file.txt");
var pathOnDisk = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uri.AbsolutePath);
// Resulting incorrectly in "C:\MyWebsite\my%20file.txt"
```

Without mucking around, and using an official solution not string.Replace, how can one get the unescaped path from the uri, or alternatively, map the path to disk without using the escaped characters?

Comment: you would have to find the substring of where the space is and replace it with a string.Empty

Answer (score 0):

Just decode it:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/my file.txt");
var pathOnDisk = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uri.AbsolutePath);
var decoded = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(pathOnDisk);
```